# How to jump to a specific heading in a man page?

Tags: command-line-interface, man

I've set a filetype in vim for this.  I want the help program to be `man`. Of course this does not work. For instance, with `ssh_config`'s manpage, if I am on a word, say `ServerAliveCountMax`,
I get an error, since there is no man pager for `ServerAliveCountMax` -- it's inside `ssh_config`'s manpage.

From the command line, is there any way to jump to a string or run some type of command inside `man`? Just like how `info` can take me to the `Miscellaneous` section of `screen`'s info page:

```
info screen Miscellaneous
```

Is this possible with `man`?  Even running a search would serve...

---

For OSX/*BSD with `/usr/bin/man`, this works:

```
man -P 'less -p PATTERN' ssh_config
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the command line for GNU `man`:

```
man --pager='less -p ^ENVIRONMENT' man
```

or for BSD `man`:

```
man -P 'less -p ^ENVIRONMENT' man
```

will jump to the "ENVIRONMENT" heading of the man page for `man`.

Here is a handy function:

```
mans () {    # Bash
    local pages string
    if [[ -n $2 ]]
    then
        pages=(${@:2})
        string="$1"
    else
        pages=$1
    fi
    # GNU man
    man ${2:+--pager="less -p \"$string\" -G"} ${pages[@]}
    # BSD man
    # man ${2:+-P "less -p \"$string\" -G"} ${pages[@]}
}
```

Examples:

Use normally:

```
mans bash
```

Go to the "DESCRIPTION" heading:

```
mans ^DESCRIPTION bash
```

Go to the "DESCRIPTION" heading of each man page in succession (press `q` and `Enter` to go to the next one):

```
mans ^DESCRIPTION bash ksh zsh
```

Go to the "Parameter Expansion" sub-heading (you can search for any string using regular expressions):

```
mans '^ *Parameter Expansion' bash
```

Search for the most recent regex you've used in Less:

```
mans '' bash
```

The match that you searched for won't be highlighted. If you'd prefer it to be, just remove the `-G` from the options to `less`.

This function makes no attempt to handle the other arguments and options that `man` supports.

Comment: promising, I edited my question, I see you ran that using either macports or linux, I have a -P option in the crappy BSD style option list... trying that.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but thanks again!  BAH, I can't upvote your new answer again :(

Comment: @Chiggsy: I take it the `-P` worked. If so, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: For the record, I upvoted your original answer. It was completely correct.  Your edit , i was unable to upvote.  I wanted to though...

Comment: @Chiggsy: Should I add the `-P` BSD-style to my answer for future reference?

Comment: Yes.  It was definitely just dialect difference.

Answer (score 6):

I use a simple trick to jump relatively fast between sections in man pages:
I hit `/^[A-Z]` and then I can press <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> to jump forward and backwards.

The search regex utilizes the basic structure of typical man pages - The main sections are written in capital letters and they begin a line without indentation therefor they should appear at the beginning of lines.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the `--pager`/`-P` solution, because `man` might be used but not be called directly (e.g. when you use `git help ...`). So using an envvar is more flexible. But I find using `PAGER='less ...` kind of redundant, because `less` is usually the default pager anyway. You can use the `LESS` envvar to pass on parameters directly to `less`. This also has less quoting issues. E.g. this will correctly jump to the right section, even though it has a space in it:

```
LESS="-p file system" git help glossary
```

Comment: Up to the top with this answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PAGER` variable for this run to avoid BSD/GNU compatibility problem.

Use `"` quotes if the section title contains spaces:

`PAGER='less -p ^"ENVIRONMENT"' man man`

Answer (score 1):

`/` in less will do a forward search, and `?` will do a reverse search. Press `h` to see a full list.

Comment: See my comment above, and actually, my question.

Answer (score 1):

In man you can type `/` followed by a pattern to match e.g. to find the DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS section of the screen man page you would type

```
/^DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS
```

Comment: Yes.  This is true, but you have to be _in_ man to do it.  I want to get from the shell to that in one step.